# Destruct with a pointer to object

Tags: c++, pointers, object, destructor, delete-operator

If an object exists as such:

```
MyClass obj;
```

To call a member function:

```
obj.myMemberFunction();
```

Then to call the destructor of that object after it fulfills its purpose:

```
delete obj;
```

However, lets say I have a pointer to an object:

```
MyClass* obj;
```

To call a member function:

```
obj->myMemberFunction();
```

Now... How do I call the destructor on this object?

Comment: Same. You don't need delete your object, what created on stack

Comment: You mustn't call destructor for your object that was instantiated as `MyClass obj;` - it's allocated as automatic variable and the destructor will be called automatically when exiting the scope.

Answer (score 6):

You've got it backwards; do `delete` in the second case and *not* the first:

```
MyClass obj;
obj.myMemberFunction();
//delete obj;
//^^^^^^^^^^^
// NO! `obj` has automatic storage and will
// be destroyed automatically when it goes out
// of scope.
```

`delete` expects a pointer to a *dynamically*-allocated object:

```
MyClass* obj = new MyClass;
obj->myMemberFunction();
delete obj;
```

Comment: Worth noting: Unless you really need to use pointers you probably avoid them. Use the normal objects for most situations so that they are correctly destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

If you create it with

```
MyClass obj;
```

you do nothing to delete it. If you create it with

```
MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
```

you use

```
delete obj;
```

to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The [operator delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete/) is intended to be used with pointers that stores the adresses of areas allocated on the heap thanks to the corresponding [operator new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new/).

```
void function () 
{
  int * pt;

  pt = new int;

  *pt = 42;

  delete pt; // memory released
}
```

Memory allocated on the stack is automaticly released at the end of the corresponding scope :

```
void function () 
{
  int i;

  i = 42;

} // memory released
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `MyClass obj;`, the object is allocated on the stack, as opposed to on the heap. In this case, the object is destroyed automatically then it goes out of scope. The compiler generates code to ensure the destructor is called. So you don't delete the object explicitly.

`delete` is used when an object is allocated on the heap. For example:

```
MyClass* pobj = new MyClass;
// Do something with pobj...
delete pobj;
```

Comment: Speaking strictly in terms of the C++ language, the physical storage location is not relevant, but the storage _duration_ is. That is "automatic storage"/"dynamic storage" vs this "stack"/"heap". That and the type of `delete`'s operand.

Comment: @Dabbler, `s/MyClass pobj/MyClass *pobj/`